# How to insert check constraint for phone number in mysql?

Tags: mysql, regex, database, constraints

I have a table of customers and I want the phone number to have the following form '+906924679833' but whenever I insert something like that I get a 'Check constraint '...' is violated'.

```
CREATE TABLE customer
(
    AFM int(30) not null,
    name varchar(30),
    surname varchar(30),
    phone char(13) not null,
    address varchar(30),
    DOY varchar(4),
    constraint chk_phone check (REGEXP_LIKE(phone, '^\+\d{12}$')),
    PRIMARY KEY(AFM)
);
```

I want to insert the following values

```
INSERT INTO customer (AFM, name, surname, phone, address, DOY)
VALUES
   (1023452569, 'Charlie', 'Hunnam', '+306943625956', 'California', 'A');
```

Thank you!!!

Comment: Cannot reproduce using the given snippets in [this DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uFiVjJYLgfatvpny2VzGBD/0)

Comment: @esqew I use the mysql server

Comment: If you look closely at the fiddle linked, I have set the DB type as MySQL.

Comment: `'^[+][0-9]{12}$'`?

Comment: @esqew the thing is that it's running on the DB Fiddle and not on my mysql server

Comment: Ok, but that doesn't change the fact that the code you've provided here doesn't reproduce the error of which you speak in a clean installation of MySQL, which means that something that's currently outside the scope of the question or not included in your code here that is causing the issue you're seeing. Using fiddles is a common debugging tactic to prove this out.

Comment: @esqew I appreciate your help but I dont think that this is a reason for you to downvote the question, becuase I am a studentand  the problem was at the regex and it is now fixed. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @RyszardCzech Thank you so much it works!!

Comment: What version of MySQL?  Old versions accepted the clause but did nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use simpler construct for digits, `[0-9]`, and escape plus in a proper way, or i- if in doubt - put it into a bracket expression:

```sql
'^[+][0-9]{12}$'
```